# XPM, Eventsystem and creating new page - Eventsystem not triggered

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, event-system

I have an EventSystem handler that sets a default metadata schema if a new page is created. This works perfect if I create the page in the CME. But if I create a new page (based on a Page Type) in XPM, the EventSystem doesn't kick in. So my metadata schema isn't set on the page. (Metadata schema has 1 required text-field, with a default value)

In my EventSystem handler I subscribe using the following code:

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, LoadEventArgs>(SetDefaultSchema, EventPhases.Processed);
```

I also tried this (CrudEventArgs):

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, CrudEventArgs>(SetDefaultSchema, EventPhases.Processed);
```

Both work like a charm in the CME, but not when the page is created in XPM. Any clues what I'm doing wrong?

(Tridion 2011, SP1 HR2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess would be that when you are creating a new page based on page type in XPM, XPM is actually cloning/copy and paste the type and then updating it with the appropriate values. Recommend subscribing to `CopyEventArgs` to confirm.

**Update**

Creating a new page in XPM using a Page Type should fire `CopyEventArgs`, however, copy operation is done on system, and works on the persisted state of the item, not the transient state, so any property you change on the event args will not be copied to the destination. I would recommend that in the `Processed` phase of `CopyEventArgs` you will have access to `CopiedObject` which you can use to update.

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, CopyEventArgs>(PageCopyEventHandler, EventPhases.Processed);

public void PageCopyEventHandler(Page source, CopyEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)
{
    if (phase == EventPhases.Processed && e.CopiedObject != null)
    {
        Page page = (Page) e.CopiedObject;
        bool isCheckedOutAlready = false;
        if (!page.IsCheckedOut)
        {
            isCheckedOutAlready = true;
            page.CheckOut();
        }
        page.MetadataSchema = SomeSchema;
        if (isCheckedOutAlready)
        {
            page.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            page.Save(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In which case you could probably set the metadata schema on the "original" page prototype and skip this in XPM?

Comment: @Likhan: works like a charm. In my original handler I checked for `page.Id.IsUriNull`, but this was never the case when the page was created in XPM. It worked in the CME, but not in XPM. Your handler together with my original `LoadEventArgs` handler for CME actions is good enough for me. Thanks.